# Laravel: PDO Class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

During deploy laravel project on Centos, I have gotten this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/html/<laravel_project_name>/config/database.php on line 16
```

I have enabled pdo extension with editing php.ini file.

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

And when I try to php -v, I got following error.

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator in Unknown on line 0
```

I have restarted httpd server after edit php.ini file.
Please help me to fix this error.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting means there is an extension=... or zend_extension=... line in your php configuration files (usually php.ini) that is trying to load that extension but it cannot load the files for it, either because it does not exist or it does not have permissions to access it.

In this case you have set all of the below in your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

But have they actually been installed?

Given you are using CentOS, try run the following to install `PDO`:

`yum install php-pdo php-mysqli`

If it is already installed then please check the permissions to `/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so` have been set appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Line 16 of database.php is this

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS
```

This means PDO class does not exist.

You can install pdo and restart if required this way

```
 yum install php-pdo

 service httpd restart
```

That said check this link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Installing PDO on Unix systems

```
PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0. You may need to enable the PDO driver for your database of choice; consult the documentation for database-specific PDO drivers to find out more about that.
```

To create an instance of pdo in laravel you can do this way

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```