# Moving Laravel project from windows to RedHat 7 - Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: sql-server, laravel, pdo, redhat, php-7.1

**This question is not a duplicate of similar questions because I have installed PHP PDO extensions .**

I have to move a Laravel 5.4 project which is now on Windows / IIS with Microsoft SQL Database to Linux Red Hat 7.4

I have: Apache httpd24 runing, with php 7.1 (rh-php71 package) installed with PDO, PDFO_ODBC extensions installed. PHP is working in php-fpm mode.

Everything works fine until the first access to SQL database (at the login :) )
when i get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class 'PDO' not found
```

After 3 days of work and learn is there a solution another then migrate database to Maria or MySQL ?!

Later edit: I have added in php.ini:

```
extension=pdo.so
```

and now the new error is:

```
    Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
    could not find driver (SQL: select top 1 * from [users] 
    where [email] = radu.cruceana@tiriacleasing.ro)
```

[image: phpinfo() result]
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193926/laravel-pdo-class-not-found-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: PDO Class not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193926/laravel-pdo-class-not-found-error)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin 
My question is NOT a duplicate in any way ...
As I sad I already installed PDO extensison, when I run php -m I see PDO extension there.

Comment: @Radu I didn't mark it as duplicate, I've just posted a question with a similar issue which you might want to check.

Comment: @commonsense 
There is an important diference I've installed all PDO extensisons/

Comment: It sounds like you have a different PHP version, or at least extensions, running in fpm as opposed to cli.

Comment: @Devon, I have 71. from the rh-php71 packagae - (red hat collection)
I understood that fpm mode is the preffered one as it is faster.
In cli mode of php 7.1 there is pdo extension for mssqlserver?

Comment: Yes... it seems like you need to hire a redhat sysadmin if this is a business site.  You may get it working but how will you manage if something breaks and your site is offline?

Comment: I'm also an "admin" :) I have installed php7.1 stack from Remi + pdo_sqlrv + msodbcsql from Microsoft and now iut's working. i had to install also the php71-php-fpm from remi repo

Comment: @Devon the package that solved was php71-php-sqlsrv which require msodbcsql :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can tell, PDO alone can't connect to a sql server database.

You should also install [pdo_sqlsrv](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql) or connect via FreeTDS + pdo_dblib.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have one more step to do.

 I've installed php71 from Remi repo. 

Now I have in /opt 2 php stacks the original one and the one from remi repo,

How to tell httpd which one to use I want to set it to use the one from remi repo.

Comment: I had to remove rh-php71-php-fpm and to install php71-php-fpm from remi repo